# Coupon collector with packs and specific desired coupons?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I'm looking into a particular variation of the coupon collector's problem where:

- There are $n$ types of coupons
- Each draw is a pack consisting of $k \leq n$ *distinct* coupons

  - Each coupon has an equal probability of appearing in a pack
  - *Different* packs may contain duplicate coupons
- We are interested in $m \leq n$ *specific* coupons

The question is: what's the expected number of packs until we've obtained all $m$ specific coupons?

---

I'm not at all confident in my formulation of the problem above, but here's a concrete example that I'm thinking of:

Suppose there's a trading card game with $n=28$ different cards sold in packs of $k=5$ distinct cards, and we are only interested in collecting $m=10$ specific cards out of the 28.

- This should differ from the more common variation I've found where we're interested in collecting *any* $m \leq n$ unique cards. In particular, we may have already obtained $n-1 > m$ unique cards while still missing the last specific card we want.
- I've been trying to formulate this as obtaining the first $m$ cards (WLOG by re-labelling?), but got stuck with this approach.
  E.g. the original coupon collector has this [trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Calculating_the_expectation) of defining $t_i$ to be the number of draws to collect the $i^{th}$ coupon after having $i-1$ coupons and summing such $t_i$'s. So I've been trying to do something similar and defining $t_{i,j}$ to be the number of draws to collect $j<\min(k,m-i)$ of the remaining desired coupons after having $i<m$ desired coupons, but then they form a probability tree and things get messy and I needed more knowledge and technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the probability that you’ve collected all $m$ desired cards after $t$ draws of $k$ distinct coupons is

$$
\mathsf P(T\le t)=\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^i\binom mi\left(\frac{\binom{n-i}k}{\binom nk}\right)^t\;,
$$

since there are $\binom mi$ ways to select $i$ missing cards and $\binom{n-i}k$ out of the possible $\binom nk$ packs miss all of them.

Thus the expected value of the number $T$ of draws required is

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf E[T]
&=&
\sum_{t=0}^\infty\mathsf P(T\gt t)
\\
&=&
\sum_{t=0}^\infty\left(1-\mathsf P(T\le t)\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{t=0}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{i+1}\binom mi\left(\frac{\binom{n-i}k}{\binom nk}\right)^t
\\
&=&
\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{i+1}\binom mi\sum_{t=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\binom{n-i}k}{\binom nk}\right)^t
\\
&=&
\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{(-1)^{i+1}\binom mi}{1-\frac{\binom{n-i}k}{\binom nk}}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

For your example with $n=28$, $k=5$ and $m=10$ this comes out as

$$
\frac{11532680255947485468964}{739977234759737482325}\approx15.6
$$

([Wolfram|Alpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%20of%20%28%28-1%29%5E%28i%2B1%29%20*%20binom%20%2810%2Ci%29%29%20%2F%20%281%20-%20binom%20%2828-i%2C5%29%20%2F%20binom%20%2828%2C5%29%29%20for%20i%3D1..10)).

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much for your answer! I ended up coding a simulation but having the analytical solution is really nice and it did line up giving me ~15.58 average over 1 million runs. I will have to carefully go through and try to understand your answer. Thank you so much :)